# Oracle DB audit trails

Tags: oracle, logging, audit

Someone (or something) actually updated a value in my table wrongly. I am trying to find out when the update happened. Unfortunately, there is no audit trigger being created for the said table.

Is there other ways or logs that I can check and verify what SQL statements were run at what time?

I had tried to look at v$sql table, but I don't think that table is capturing all the SQL statements being performed on the database. E.g. I specifically did an UPDATE statement, but it is not captured in the v$sql table.

Can I look at the redo.log? However, I do not know how to interpret this log.

Answer (score 2):

Your only real option is logminer, which isn't for the faint of heart.

The documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm

`v$sql` rows may get aged out after a while. Did you account for case sensitivity when looking in `v$sql`?

```
select * from v$sql where upper(sql_fulltext) like '%UPDATE%';
```

Comment: Indeed it is not for the faint hearted. :( Any other tool to read the redo.log? Also, I had accounted for the case sensitivity when I look at v$sql. I understand the rows get aged, but the record that I updated was just recent and immediate.

Comment: There's no other way I'm afraid.